# Two types of variables in a single Heatmap (using R)

Tags: r, variables, heatmap, correlation

I have to plot data from immunized animals in a way to visualize possible correlations in protection. As a background, when we vaccinate an animal it produces antibodies, which might or not be linked to protection. We immunized bovine with 9 different proteins and measured antibody titers which goes up to 1.5 (Optical Density (O.D.)). We also measured tick load that goes up to 5000. Each animal have different titers for each protein and different tick loads, maybe some proteins are more important for protection than the others, and we think that a heatmap could illustrate it.

**TL;DR:** Plot a heatmap with one variable (Ticks) that goes from 6 up to 5000, and another variable (Prot1 to Prot9) that goes up to 1.5.

A sample of my data:

```
Animal  Group   Ticks   Prot1   Prot2   Prot3   Prot4   Prot5   Prot6   Prot7   Prot8   Prot9
G1-54-102   control 3030    0.734   0.402   0.620   0.455   0.674   0.550   0.654   0.508   0.618
G1-130-102  control 5469    0.765   0.440   0.647   0.354   0.528   0.525   0.542   0.481   0.658
G1-133-102  control 2070    0.367   0.326   0.386   0.219   0.301   0.231   0.339   0.247   0.291
G3-153-102  vaccinated  150 0.890   0.524   0.928   0.403   0.919   0.593   0.901   0.379   0.647
G3-200-102  vaccinated  97  1.370   0.957   1.183   0.658   1.103   0.981   1.051   0.534   1.144
G3-807-102  vaccinated  606 0.975   0.706   1.058   0.626   1.135   0.967   0.938   0.428   1.035
```

I have little knowledge in R, but I'm really excited to learn more about it. So feel free to put whatever code you want and I will try my best to understand it.

Thank you in advance.
Luiz

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to use the `ggplot2` package to create a heatmap. You will need to convert your data frame from wide format to long format. It is also important to convert the `Ticks` column from numeric to factor if the numbers are discrete.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  gather(Prot, Value, starts_with("Prot"))

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = factor(Ticks), y = Prot, fill = Value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Animal  Group   Ticks   Prot1   Prot2   Prot3   Prot4   Prot5   Prot6   Prot7   Prot8   Prot9
'G1-54-102'   control 3030    0.734   0.402   0.620   0.455   0.674   0.550   0.654   0.508   0.618
'G1-130-102'  control 5469    0.765   0.440   0.647   0.354   0.528   0.525   0.542   0.481   0.658
'G1-133-102'  control 2070    0.367   0.326   0.386   0.219   0.301   0.231   0.339   0.247   0.291
'G3-153-102'  vaccinated  150 0.890   0.524   0.928   0.403   0.919   0.593   0.901   0.379   0.647
'G3-200-102'  vaccinated  97  1.370   0.957   1.183   0.658   1.103   0.981   1.051   0.534   1.144
'G3-807-102'  vaccinated  606 0.975   0.706   1.058   0.626   1.135   0.967   0.938   0.428   1.035",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: It is not exactly the solution I imagined, but I think it works. Is there any way that I can add some sort of bar with colors, or some sort of legend to indicate which one of them are from the control or vaccinated group?

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of `ggplot2` / the tidyverse, you don't even need to explicitly load the `viridis`-package. The scale is included via `scale_fill_viridis_c()`. Exciting times!